# Android Different layouts for different screen resolutions

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Is this done by creating identically named xml files and placing each in drawable-ldpi drawable-hdpi folders? At the moment I am doing this but only different images are being used. No matter how I change the ldpi folders xml the hdpi's is used.

Am i doing something wrong? Or can I force the emulator to update (I am pushing the current apk to it) ?

Comment: That sounds right but how do you force the emulator to ldpi mode?

Comment: @DanS - you can affect what density the emulator thinks it is using by changing the `-scale` and/or `-dpi-device` values on the emulator command line. (These can also be set with the AVD manager in Eclipse.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder modifiers `-ldpi`, `-hdpi`, etc., can be used for other resource folders besides `drawable`. You can also have `layout-ldpi`, `layout-hdpi`, etc. Each would contain an identically named layout xml file, each with different xml (or not).

Be aware that the logic used in the emulator to decide what folder to use is rather complicated and depends on both the emulated dpi of the device and the scaling factor used for rendering the emulator screen. You may think you are emulating an ldpi device, but the emulator may still be deciding to bind the hdpi resources.